# How to simplify condition check

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to simplify the following condition check in rails

```
params[:name].include?params[:first]||params[:another_name].include?params[:first]
```

Answer (score 1):

for example like that

```
[:name, :another_name].any?{|key| params[key].include?(params[:first])}
```

but, personally me, i'd put it in a controller's method and give it some meaningful name